# Decrypting a file knowing only the password

Tags: encryption, passwords, file-encryption, key

I have encrypted a file using a program with a password and would like to decrypt it on another device just with the password. Is there any software that takes the password, runs it through all key derivation functions and decrypts the file? The algorithm used is AES 256.

Comment: In addition to the password, the key derivation function also requires a salt.  Do you know where the salt is stored?

Comment: Do you want to decrypt it? Or do you want to know if somebody can decrypt this file by bruteforcing?

Comment: Similar to: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226935/write-a-python-or-c-program-to-guess-the-key/226950#226950

Comment: And in most cases the iteration count, and sometimes other parameters like a 'context' or 'label'. And the mode, because AES alone encrypts only 16 octets exactly, which almost no files are.